# Jquery hasClass animate

Tags: jquery, html, class, jquery-animate, pageload

Im trying to get a hasClass animation to work on pageload however apparently its harder than it sounds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('html').hasClass('first')) {
        // Then animate
    $(".second").animate,500({marginTop: "30px"});
  } else {
        // Then normal
    $(".second").animate,500({marginTop: "0px"});
  }
});
```

Heres a codepen example
http://codepen.io/Maksketch/pen/ZLrwGM

If however solves this, could include a 5 second delay on animation, then that would be great!

Note: I dont want a toggle function. Just when loading current page.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('html').hasClass('first')` to `$('html div').hasClass('first')` and also you have to write the animate like `.animate( {marginTop: "30px"},500);`

For the delay use `.delay(time in seconds)` like `$(".second").delay(5000).animate`

> (`5000 = 5 seconds`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('html div').hasClass('first')) {
    // Then animate
    $(".second").delay(5000).animate({
      marginTop: "30px"
    }, 500);
  } else {
    // Then normal
    $(".second").animate({
      marginTop: "0px"
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #999;
  font-family: arial;
}
.first {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 0px 6px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 4;
}
.second {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(110, 170, 0, 1);
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="first">If I exist show second</div>
  <div class="second">Hide me if first is non-existing</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Carsten (dansker?)
Seems to work in the snippet! Ill try it out on my site. Thank you!

Comment: Yes i'm danish, but please keep any conversation in english

Answer (score 0):

multiple errors.

First, it is not `html` that has a class `.first`, but a div. You can use either `$(div).hasClass('.first')` or simply `$('.first')` in your condition.

Then, the call to animate is incorrect. It should be:

```
$(".second").animate({marginTop: "0px"}, 500);
```

Note that if you open your developer console, it would tell you the error, i.e. `Uncaught TypeError: 500 is not a function`.

Finally, to add a delay, you can simply use `.delay`, for example:

```
$(".second").delay(500).animate({marginTop: "30px"}, 500);
```

In the end, you get:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.first')) {
        // Then animate
    $(".second").delay(5000).animate({marginTop: "30px"}, 500);
  } else {
        // Then normal
    $(".second").animate({marginTop: "0px"}, 500);
  }
});
```

here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gb4g4yL/).

Comment: He want a delay on 5 seconds, not 0.5 seconds

Comment: Thank you Derlin! However how do I test it in CodePen? or do I need to use jsfiddle?

Comment: not so familiar with codepen, I added a link to a working jsfiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You better use `$('.first').length`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.first').length) {
    // Then animate
    $(".second").animate({
      marginTop: "30px"
    }, 500);
  } else {
    // Then normal
    $(".second").animate({
      marginTop: "0px"
    }, 500);
  }
});
```